# update-rc.d vs chkconfig

Tags: linux, configuration, startup, rc

I have tried to get my head around how to configure the application startups and shutdowns in linux. Can someone explain me what the difference between using update-rc and chkconfig is? Is it two ways of doing the exact same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chkconfig` - updates and queries runlevel information for system services

`update-rc.d` updates the System V style init script links /etc/rcrunlevel.d/NNname whose target is the script /etc/init.d/name.

> Is it two ways of doing the exact same thing?

Yes.  The equivalent to chkconfig is update-rc.d